# Laravel: difference between using a Trait or extending a model

Tags: laravel, design-patterns, traits, extend

We're working on a Laravel application with a scheduling module. The module has three types of classes that can be put in an agenda: Task, Event and Department. We've therefore come up with the following class diagram:
[image: Class Diagram]
Now, our question: if we were to realise this diagram, should we use a Trait or should we extend a Plannable model.

Plannable model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Plannable extends Model
{
    // Code
}
```

Task model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Plannable;

class Task extends Plannable
{
    // Code
}
```

Or should we use this as a trait:

Plannable trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait Plannable
{
    // Code
}
```

Task model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Plannable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    use Plannable;
    // Code
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using laravel's polymorphic relationships? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the trait. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Comment: I second the vote for a polymorphic relationship.

Comment: No I'm not trying to have a relationship. I'd like to prevent duplicate code in all 3 models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending a parent/abstract class is best used when the models all share common *characteristics* but behave (function) in a unique way.  For instance, `Car`s and `Motorcycle`s are both `Vehicle`s.  They share common characteristics (e.g. headlights, indicators, engines, transmissions, etc.), but how to `operate()` them is unique from class to class.

Traits, on the other hand, are better used when the using classes (or Eloquent models in this case) require common *functionality* (i.e. methods) despite having different characteristics.

Without knowing more about your project, it seems like you're looking for the latter with each model having common functionality (perhaps `addToCalendar()`, `reschedule()`, etc.) despite having different characteristics.

Answer (score 5):

When you try to extend a class, means that "is a" relation, Car extends Vehicle, Car "is a" Vehicle. In your example, Task "is a" Plannable. Is it though?

On the other hand, traits use different approach, kinda like "Car uses wheels". In your example again, Task uses Plannable. Looks better than extending I guess?

Its hard to say more without understanding the which functions you will trait for this implementation. I hope, it gives some ideas.

Comment: Nice comparison. What I'm trying to achieve is the following: I'd like to make some generic code that applies to all models that can be placed in the calendar. I'd like to prevent writing the same code in all three separate models